# How to get the weekday names using Intl?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

I'd like to display in my i18n-ed app a list of the 7 weekdays:

```
Sunday, Monday, Tuesday... Saturday
```

I rely on the [Intl global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) for formatting date/time but I can't find an easy way to get *only* the weekday names.

I thought I could add some days to the EPOCH time, to reach the first day of the week, but I'm failing to find a formatter printing just the weekday.

```
var date = new Date(0);
date.setDate(4 + day);
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  var weekday = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(["en"], {
      weekday: "short" // ?? what should I put here
  }).format(date);
  console.log(weekday);
}
```

Output:

```
Sunday, January 4, 1970
Monday, January 5, 1970
Tuesday, January 6, 1970
Wednesday, January 7, 1970
Thursday, January 8, 1970
Friday, January 9, 1970
Saturday, January 10, 1970
```

Desired output:

```
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
```

I also would like to have a shorter version of the days, such as `Sun, Mon, Tue...`.

Alternatively, is there a way to get the weekday *strings* from `Intl`? I tried to explore the object via console but I couldn't find them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was misled because I was using the Intl polyfill, which does not support yet `{ weekday: "short" }` as option.

Using native Intl implementations works as expected.

Comment: Here's some shorter code to return all the weekday names: `for (var day = 5; day <= 11; day++) {  new Date(1970, 1 - 1, day).toLocaleString('de', { weekday: 'short' /* or 'long' */ });  }`

Comment: `new Array(7).fill().map((_, d) => new Date(2001, 0, d).toLocaleString('es', { weekday: 'short' }))` ;-)

Answer (score 12):

### my solution in 2021 with es6

```js
/**
 * Return list of days
 *  localeName : name of local, f.e. en-GB, default es-MX
 * ✅ weekday    : format of weekday short/long (Default)
 */
function daysForLocale(localeName = 'es-MX', weekday = 'long') {
  const {format} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeName, { weekday });
  return [...Array(7).keys()]
    .map((day) => format(new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 5, day))));
}

// ##############################################################
// testing daysForLocale function
// ##############################################################
console.log(daysForLocale());
// ['domingo','lunes',...,'viernes','sábado']
console.log(daysForLocale('en-GB', 'short'));
// ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri','Sat']
console.log(daysForLocale('ja-JP', 'short'));
// ['日', '月', '火','水', '木', '金','土']
```

Comment: on my local this method works perfectly but somehow when the same unit tests run on jenkins machine index 0 is Monday

Comment: OK the difference is that my local timezone is EST but the jenkins machine is on GMT

Comment: I like this answer. Here to make it work in any timezone:
`function daysForLocale(localeName = 'en-US', weekday = 'long') {
  let now = new Date()
  const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeName, { weekday }).format;
  return [...Array(7).keys()]
    .map((day) => format(new Date().getTime() - ( now.getDay() - day  ) * 86400000 ));
}`

Comment: Why specifically use 2021 and 5 as date arguments?

Answer (score 7):

```js
 const weekdayDateMap = {
  Mon: new Date('2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z'),
  Tue: new Date('2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z'),
  Wed: new Date('2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z'),
  Thu: new Date('2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z'),
  Fri: new Date('2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z'),
  Sat: new Date('2020-01-11T00:00:00.000Z'),
  Sun: new Date('2020-01-12T00:00:00.000Z'),
};
const shortWeekdays = Object.keys(weekdayDateMap);

const getDayOfWeek = (shortName, locale = 'en-US', length = 'short') =>
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { weekday: length }).format(weekdayDateMap[shortName]);

const getDaysOfWeek = (locale = 'en-US', length = 'short') =>
  shortWeekdays.map(shortName => getDayOfWeek(shortName, locale, length));


console.log(getDayOfWeek('Mon', 'de-DE')) // "Mo"

console.log(getDaysOfWeek('de-DE')) // ["Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"]
```

**Note:**

If you're calling the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` formatter many times a second, it's more efficient to create the formatter once and re-use it.

Comment: if this script runs on west of London the week start with Sunday, if it runs on east of London the week start from Monday.

Comment: @ShuaiWang Hm not sure why but updated `new Date` strings to be ISO

Answer (score 1):

`Intl` (ergo `Intl.js` as well) doesn't have an API to get weekday names yet, so you'll have to do the hack-thing of querying a bunch of days with the right options.  It's possible it may [add support for doing so in the future](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287677), but right now you're basically out of luck.  (At least, unless you manually augment `Intl.js` with a fix.)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to improve on the most popular answer; Also to answer the question:

> Why use Date.UTC(2021, 1, day+1) to initialize?

Because, you need to find an actual calendar week where you can extract the weekdays string from.

```js
    function getWeekdayLocale(localeName = 'fr', weekday = 'long') {
          const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeName, { weekday }).format;
          return [...Array(7).keys()]
            .map((day) => format(new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 1, day+1))));
    }
    console.log(getWeekdayLocale())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that does not have to hardcode the start date

```js
const format = (date) => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ca', { 'weekday': 'long' }).format(date);
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0); /* normalise */
d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() - 1); /* Saturday */
const localeDayNames = [...Array(7)]
  .map((_, i) => format(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)));
console.log(localeDayNames);
```

Answer (score -2):

Much simpler solution:

```
let d = new Date();
let day_options = {
    timeZone: "America/New_York",
    weekday:"short"
};
let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([],day_options);
console.log(formatter.format(d));
```

Output: Thu

Comment: This is always today's date, so my output is "Mon". OP is also asking for the names of all the days, not just today's.